# Does changing a column length from varchar 18 to varchar 8 improve search speed drastically?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a Mysql database with ~500k rows. I have a column that is basically a short url used as an index for each row. I can make the index 8 char/varchar or 18. I want to know if the extra 10 chars will really slow my searches down drastically.  A pro to varchar 18 is I won't have to generate a short url. Whereas, if I do varchar or char 8, I will. The index will be used for retrieving comments, updating the entry, etc. The index however will be unique regardless.

Thanks

Comment: if the field's indexed, then the DB will be comparing the index hashes, not the strings. e.g. the length of the string doesn't matter, **IF** an index is being used. the only time the length actually matters is confirming that the hash actually represents the string being compared, e.g. checking that no hash collisions occured, and would only be done on a VERY small subset of your table.

Comment: Have you tried running benchmarks with sample data to find out?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Do you know of any good benchmarking tools?

Comment: @MarcB I did not know about this. I asked because I read everywhere that to improve performance shorten the length of your index. Any material I can read on this?

Comment: @MarcB, only MySQL tables with the `MEMORY` access method support hash indexes. The rest of the access methods in standard MySQL support BTREE indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not drastically. Search speed in B+-tree indexes varies as the number of index reads, which varies with *log<sub>x</sub>(N),* where *N* is the number of index entries and *x* is the number of keys per index block, which in turn is inversely proportional to their length. You can see it is a sub-linear relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in index performance between 8-char and 18-char column values is not zero. But it is quite small.  Index performance deteriorates more markedly when you're dealing with stuff like 255-character indexes.

You should be fine either way with a half-megarow table unless you have really extraordinary performance requirements.

When you're done with the table's initial load, do `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to make the indexes work optimally.  If the table gets lots of `DELETE` or `INSERT` operations, try to find a time of day or week when you routinely can redo the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` operation.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html